# Pass optional command-line switch to Airflow task

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG with parameter defined as follows:

```
with DAG("some_dag", params={
    "foo": Param("", type="string"),
    "woo": Param("", type="string")
}) as dag:
    some_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id="some_task",
        spark_jar_task={
            'main_class_name': 'com.some_app.SomeApp',
            'parameters': ["--foo={{ params.foo }}", "--woo={{ params.woo }}", "--moo=1"]
        }
    )
```

I'm not sure how to make this parameter optional. For example parameters should contain just `["moo=1"]` if neither `params.foo` nor `params.woo` is provided.

Comment: create python operator that returns the command line (as list) according all conditions and set it the parameters:{{ti.xcom_pull(taskids='cmd_task')}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `user_defined_macros` parameter when instantiating DAG and pass your decision function here. See [Templates reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

Below is sample code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Sequence

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator

class ExtraParamsOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ("some_param",)

    def __init__(self, some_param: dict, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.some_param = some_param

    def execute(self, context):
        print(self.some_param)
        return self.some_param

def compose_params(foo, bar):
    if not any((foo,bar)):
        return ["--baz=1"]
    else:
        return [f"--foo={foo}", f"--bar={bar}"]

with DAG(
    "test_params",
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023,10,1),
    params={
        "foo": None,
        "bar": None,
    },
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
    user_defined_macros={
        "compose_params": compose_params
    }
) as dag:
    some_task = ExtraParamsOperator(
        task_id="some_task",
        some_param={
            "key1": "value1",
            "parameters": "{{ compose_params(params.foo, params.bar) }}"
        }
    )
```

which prints this when run without parameters:

```
[2023-10-09, 14:38:01 MSK] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - {'key1': 'value1', 'parameters': ['--baz=1']}
```

and this when run with `{"foo": "something", "bar": "else"}`:

```
[2023-10-09, 14:38:26 MSK] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - {'key1': 'value1', 'parameters': ['--foo=something', '--bar=else']}
```

Comment: I see, this `render_template_as_native_obj` seems to be responsible for correctly handling the array. It looks like having a `"{{ compose_params(...) }}"` - that's technically a string - rendering the template `{{ compose_params(...) }}` breaks it *out of the string* to become the array! That's magic - how is this possible? I saw this is how it works in [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects), but still how?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy It's documented in basic topic on [operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects): *By default, all the template_fields are rendered as strings.* And somwhere else in the docs, because it has some duplicated info. You may also check [`jinja_environment_kwargs`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG) parameter in DAG constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if`/`else` in Jinja expressions. Here's an example using a BashOperator (for reproducibility):

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Param
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="so_77258083",
    schedule_interval="@once",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    params={"foo": Param("", type="string"), "woo": Param("", type="string")},
):
    BashOperator(
        task_id="some_task",
        bash_command="echo {{ '--foo=' ~ params.foo ~ ' and --woo=' ~ params.woo if (params.foo|length and params.woo|length) else 'moo=1' }}",
    )
```

This prints `moo=1` in case `params.foo` and/or `params.woo` is empty. In the `bash_command` you see if/else logic inside a Jinja expression: `{{ ... if ... else ... }}`.

This gets a little trickier because you're using the `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator` and want to render a list of items. For each item i.e. flag I'd create an if/else Jinja expression and return an empty string if you do not want the flag to be provided:

```py
'parameters': ["{{ '--foo=' ~ params.foo if params.foo|length else '' }}", ...]
```